# Standard Usage of the word "per"

Tags: notation, conventions

Math guy here. What is the usual meaning of "x per y per z?" Is this (ignoring details) (x/y)/z or x/(y/z)?

Sorry to be mundane.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples that come to my mind are *acceleration* and *intensity*.

Acceleration is measured (in SI units) in "meters per second squared" = $\text{m}/\text{s}^2$, but it is also commonly said as "meters per second per second," which matches your first option.

Likewise, intensity is measured (in SI units) in "joules per square meter per second" = $\text{J}/(\text{m}^2\text{s})$, which also matches your first option.

I can't claim this is *always* the case, but I would guess most of the time it is.

Answer (score 1):

According to your statement "x per y per z", I read it as x/y come first then z comes later.
So it's (x/y)/z. But, this can be mistaken and it's better if we can include bracket when spell an equation.